# TSQL Sum with type

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sum

I'm writing using translate

Table1

```
id number type
1  6      111  
1  5      111
1  6      113
2  3      112
2  6      111
```

i need to sum group by value of "type" and "id"
the result I want to see

RESULT Table

```
id  type111 type112 typ113
1   11      0       6
2   6       3       0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to use [pivoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot):

```
SELECT  id,
        ISNULL([111],0) as Type111, 
        ISNULL([112],0) as Type112, 
        ISNULL([113],0) as Type113
FROM (
        SELECT  id, 
                number, 
                [type]   
        FROM Table1
    ) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT (SUM(number) FOR [type] IN ([111], [112], [113]) 
) AS PivotTable;
```

Output:

```
id          Type111     Type112     Type113
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           11          0           6
2           6           3           0

(2 rows affected)
```

In case when the variety of types is high - use dynamic SQL to build and execute query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SUM with CASE:

```
SELECT ID, 
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 111 THEN number END) AS type111,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 112 THEN number END) AS type112,  
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 113 THEN number END) AS typE113,  
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID
```